# Use with..open to read a list of xls files to copy into a single workbook with multiple sheets

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlwt

First timer here. My overall goal is to copy exactly, the data in 3 different xls files into one xls workbook with a sheet for each original xls file. In a non-programmatic sense, I want to copy and paste the data from each xls file into it's own sheet in a new workbook (xls or xlsx file). I've been using xlrd & xlwt to do this and with the help of searching around SO, I've been able to get most of the code set. However, I'm having difficult time comprehending how to use the with...open command to read the data from each original xls file and put it on it's own sheet. As you will probably learn from my code block, my Python skills are limited. Thx!

```
    import xlwt as xlwt
    from os.path import join
    import xlrd


    wb = xlwt.Workbook()
    path = r'C:\data_path\\'
    xls1 = 'file1.xls'
    xls2 = 'file2.xls'
    xls3 = 'file3.xls'

    Sheet1 = 'file1_data'
    Sheet2 = 'file2_data'
    Sheet3 = 'file3_data'

    names = [Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3]
    dataset = [path + xls1, path + xls2, path + xls3]

   for name in names:
       wb.add_sheet(name)
   for n, data in enumerate(dataset):
       **I feel there should be some type of with..open statement here**
       ws = wb.get_sheet(n)
       ws.write(0,0, data)

   wb.save(join(path,'test.xls'))
```

Comment: first problem is your paths will be `C:\data_pathfile1.xls`

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried and the errors or undesired behavior that occurred.

Comment: Yes - missed the double \\ at the end of the path definition.

Comment: When I run the code above, I get an xls file called 'test.xls' in the proper location, which is great. It has 3 sheets, all named with the proper sheet name - also great. But the contents of each sheet is just the path + file name. I realize that the way the code above is written, this is working correctly. I guess my problem is that I can't formulate an open() statement correctly to read the data of each xls file instead of just the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that each source file has only one sheet:

```
import xlwt as xlwt
from os.path import join
import xlrd

output = xlwt.Workbook()

path = r'C:\data_path\\'

xls1 = 'file1.xls'
xls2 = 'file2.xls'
xls3 = 'file3.xls'

Sheet1 = 'file1_data'
Sheet2 = 'file2_data'
Sheet3 = 'file3_data'

names = [Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3]
dataset = [path + xls1, path + xls2, path + xls3]


for n, data in enumerate(dataset):
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(data, formatting_info=True)

    sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
    r = output.add_sheet(names[n])

    for row in range(sheet.nrows):
        for column in range(sheet.ncols):
            cell_val = sheet.cell_value(rowx=row, colx=column)
            r.write(row, column, cell_val)

output.save(join(path,'test.xls'))
```

Comment: Score! Thanks much. I thought i was close but my logic was a bit off.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Feel free to accept my answer if it helped you.